# How to prevent multiple Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to scroll down the page to a certain point (height of #first_column DIV), will get json from server-side and add content to #first_column.

Now the problem is when I scroll down to the height of #first_column, there are many Ajax call almost at the same time. What I want is scroll down to the height of #first_column, call server and get json data and add content to  #first_column. The height of  #first_column changes. Then I scroll down to the height of #first_column will get the second Ajax requests.

Any suggestions?

```
<script>
   $(window).scroll(function(){
   column_height = $("#first_column").height();
   screenTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   window_height = $(window).height();

if((screenTop+window_height)>=column_height){
      $.ajax({
            url: "/service/article_json.php",
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            error: function(){
                return true;
            },
            success: function(data){ 
                $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(key,item) {

                  //Add content to #first_column

                });
            }
        });
  }
});
```

Comment: If you only want it to happen once you can unbind the scroll event from the window on success of the ajax call.

Comment: I want it happens many times if I have more contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unbind the event as the first thing you do inside the if statement and then rebind it in the Success method if you so wish.

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

Comment: I tried `$(window).bind('scroll');` to reind the event but seems not working in my success method.

Comment: You will have to rebind the entire function.  The easiest way to do that is to move it to a separate method and then just bind to that method.

Answer (score 6):

Try use a flag, for example:

```
var ajaxInProgress = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if(ajaxInProgress) return;
  ajaxInProgress = true;

  $.ajax({
    // setup here
    success: {
      // ...
      ajaxInProgress = false;
    },
    error: {
      // ...
      ajaxInProgress = false;
    }
  });
});
```

In this example when `ajaxInProgress` is set to `true` window.scroll callback will simply return and perform no operation otherwise the flag will be set to true, the call will be performed and on `success` or on `error` callback the flag will be reset to `false` which will allow for another ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Actually I still don't know why there are multiple Ajax requests in my codes. After the first ajax request, the height of #first_column DIV already changed.  `if((screenTop+window_height)>=column_height)` will not satisfy.

Comment: ..because ajax is asynchronous in the nature ;)

Comment: @Sophia it is firing multiple times because the scroll event is firing asynchronously and it is firing multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ajaxcallrunning;  //flag for ajax call

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if(ajaxcallrunning)
    {
      return;  // if a ajax call is running then return
    } 

    ajaxcallrunning = 1;      // otherwise set flag and execute ajax call

    $.ajax({
      // setup here
      success: {
         // ...
          ajaxInProgress = 0;    //reset flag after request complete
       },
       error: {
        // ...
         ajaxInProgress = 0;   //reset flag if error occurs
      }
    });
});
```